# The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library in pcl_visu alization.dll

Tags: dll, vtk, pcl

The procedure entry point
?GetAbortOutput@vtkAlgorithm@@UEAA_NXZ could not be located in the dynamic link library
C:\Users\kunal.g\source\repos\tree_support\tree_support\pcl_visu
alization.dll.

How can i solve this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUo2d.png)

The error seems due to mismatch of version
I tried to looked for a version mismatch of pcl and vtk but can't find the version of pcl as i installed it using vcpkg.
pcl_visualization.dll is avaiable in project folder & as well as in input tab under linker.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors